# Build and Array of Arrays from query result with <cfloop>

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, multidimensional-array, struct

I've got records in my MySQL projects database that have several boolean flags to help me sort the data. I have 3 categories `planning`, `landscape`, and `environmental` and 4 classes (or subcategories) for each category; `industrial`, `government`, `education`, `residential`.

My goal is to use ColdFusion to create and store the `project_id` numbers in an array of some kind that will basically have the projects sorted by category and class. That way I can grab just the industrial projects in the planning category and construct a link to that project.

So, the first position in the array would be `planning` and inside that first position would be the 4 classes, then, within that would be all of the `project_id` numbers that returned `true` for those particular criteria.

The logic I'm looking to create goes like this...

Loop over the query result, if planning = true and industrial = true, place the project id # into the planning array inside the industrial array.

How can I use `<cfloop>` to loop over the list of project records, recognize the category and class flags and construct a clean and usable dataset? Can this be handles in the query in some way?

Answer (score 0):

1. Figure out the desired data structure
2. look at your existing data structure
3. figure out the algorithm to translate from one to the other

You may `cfloop` the query, and use a large cfswitch (or large set of if-then-else) to figure out how you want to store the id in your desired data structure.  Or if you can map the class/category name as a struct key, then it might be easier.

Or you may use `cfoutput group=""` if it helps (`cfloop group=""` is available on in CF10+)

Finally, maybe you don't even need the data structure, just use Query of Queries wherever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to utilize the [Underscore.cfc library](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/) for this. For example, you could use the filter function to extract an array of structs representing the query rows you want:

```
planningArray = _.filter(queryResult, function(row){
    return (row.planning == true && row.industrial == true);
});
```